# HP network printer only prints first page

Tags: printing, hplip

My printer seems to be printing only 1 page of a PDF that I give to print. If I use Acrobat, then the following suggestion works:

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/only-first-page-print-job.html

Is there some way I can get printing to work from the system print dialogue?